# Android Studio Project Files Messed Up

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Android project files just got all messed up after I put a duplicate of the project under the same folder. As java files having xml contents and other formats I don't know, and so do xml files and gradle files. The files just got mixed and messed up randomly. `cannot load settings from file` had once showed as warning, so I deleted the two files that it indicated. Not sure if it caused this issue. How can I fix the project?

This is my MainActivity.java

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2@aar">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7925882b975de0e9c05ac44b0a44095f/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7925882b975de0e9c05ac44b0a44095f/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.support.test.espresso/espresso-idling-resource/3.0.2/6071e2b310c16836ba475a94df377e2f75928546/espresso-idling-resource-3.0.2-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

Comment: I just faced the same issue. Invalidate & Restart didn't help, clean and rebuild also. Then I went ahead and combined both of the answers below, deleted `.idea` `.gradle` and `caches` and it solved it

Comment: This is such an annoying issue. It happens after I do a little bit of refactoring!

Comment: I have the same problem, but seems like the Flutter plugin is the reason for me, because the problem has probably been happening since I added the plugin and also the messed up files seem to be filled with codes of my flutter projects. Till now I avoided serious damages by rewriting the file in android studio using the original file content (as it seems untouched and only shown messed up in android studio) but today I forgot to do that and android studio's auto saving ruined the original file. Its a very disturbing BUG

Comment: It's a common issue with Android Studio, whether you work on Android or Flutter projects, and even when I've faced this issue many times with many versions of Android studio, often, time comes when I fail to solve it, this time too and hence, the workaround for many who forgot to push the code on Git or wasn't using it, Android studio keeps a short term local history of every file, just right click the file, click on local history, and restore your files from it.

Answer (score 5):

> go to C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches and delete the caches then restart android studio again

Answer (score 2):

First Try **Invalidate Caches And Restart** If that not works, Then Do the following

Delete **.idea** and **.gradle** folder from your project directory And **.iml** files from your project directory then restart android studio